# parse.com Android Push-Notifications "X stopped working"

Tags: android, push-notification, parse-platform

I am trying to implement the push notification on my android app. I have followed their tutorial. I can receive the push notification, but when I lock the screen it suddenly says "App Name stopped working". I think this is something about losing the internet connection.

Any ideas how to fix this?

Comment: not without a stacktrace

Comment: Hi @tyczj. The problem is that the app doesn't crash in the EMU so I don't have any stacktrace

Comment: so plug a device into your computer and get it